# C# Shell Program to Pipe Echo to Text File

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple shell program and I have written a few commands for the program. Unfortunately, I also want to allow the shell to pipe an echo command out to a text file and also be able to cat said file and output the contents. The issue I am having is the way that I have written how the echo command works.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string command;

        do
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = 
            ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.Write("console > ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            command = Console.ReadLine();
            Handle(command);

        } while (command != "exit");
    }

    public static string Handle(string command)
    {

        if (command.StartsWith("echo "))
        {
            command = command.Replace("\"", "");
            Console.WriteLine(command.Substring(5));
        }

        if (command.Contains("->"))
        {
           // logic for echo "text" -> output.txt
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I was kind of leaning more to how to write the command because I substring off the echo and just write the rest. In order to create the filename and the pipe like in the comment `echo "text" -> output.txt`

Comment: I suggest you don't require quotes. Check for the "->" before you start.  If it's not there, just take the rest of the line and "echo" it.  If it is there, use `string.Split` or `string.Substring` (twice) to split the line into the text and the file name.  You may need to `string.Trim` away any surrounding whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this that takes the content from before and after the ->. You will have to validate the string of course before you run this

```
string cmd = @"echo ""text"" -> output.txt";
string text = cmd.Split(" -> ").First().Replace("echo ", "").Replace(@"""", "");
string file = cmd.Split(" -> ").Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I wasn't sure if I wanted to add LINQ or not, but I believe this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Or, a more general solution (to allow extra commands).  First I create a dictionary of commands.  The `Action<string,string>` type represents a delegate to a function that takes two strings as as parameters.  The `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` means that the case (upper or lower) is ignored when matching:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string, string>> CommandList =
    new Dictionary<string, Action<string, string>>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        {"echo", EchoCommand},
        {"exit", ExitCommand}
    };
```

Now I have to implement the commands.  The `echo` command is close to what you want to do (I don't bother trying to write to the file, but I get it to the point where you could).  The `exit` command is empty (I just let it fall through).  You may want to refactor that behavior.

```
private static void EchoCommand(string commandText, string file)
{
    var fileNote = string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) ? string.Empty : $" ({file})";
    Console.WriteLine($"{commandText} {fileNote}");
}

private static void ExitCommand(string commandText, string file)
{

}
```

Now I need something to parse my command line.  This is a brute force hack, but it works.  The weird return type is a *`tuple`*, an entity that contain many values, in this case three named strings.

```
static (string command, string text, string file) ParseCommandLine(string commandLine)
{
    //find the first space:
    var endOfCommandIndex = commandLine.IndexOf(" ");
    if (endOfCommandIndex < 0)
    {
        return (commandLine, string.Empty, null);
    }
    //otherwise
    var command = commandLine.Substring(0, endOfCommandIndex);
    var rest = commandLine.Substring(endOfCommandIndex);
    var redirectIndex = rest.IndexOf("->");
    if (redirectIndex < 0)
    {
        //use the substring to get rid of the "->"
        return (command, rest.Substring(2).Trim(), null);
    }
    //otherwise (the "+ 2" is to get rid of the "->"
    return (command, rest.Substring(0, redirectIndex).Trim(), rest.Substring(redirectIndex + 2).Trim());
}
```

It bangs away at the command line string and parses it into a *Command*, some *Text* and possibly a *File* to redirect to.  I only changed a bit of the core of your Main function.  It ends up looking like:

```
string command, text, file;
do
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    Console.Write("console > ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    var commandLine = Console.ReadLine();
    (command, text, file) = ParseCommandLine(commandLine);
    if (CommandList.TryGetValue(command, out var commandAction))
    {
        commandAction(text, file);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Unknown Command");
    }

} while (command != "exit");
```

The `TryGetValue` call on the dictionary will return true if the command text is in the dictionary.  If it returns true, then the `commandAction` will represent the function to call (so it calls it).  If it returns false, then the command is not in the dictionary, so an error is signaled to the user.

And finally, you don't need to put the string to echo in quotes.  It just echoes whatever it finds.